# Android: Can I use Google Analytics with Firebase App

Tags: android, firebase, google-analytics

Google Analytics is great, and I really want to use it on my Android App. But I also need Firebase for user account management and crash reporting.

I am confused now that my Android app has google API key (for Analytics) in one place, and google-service.json (for Firebase) in other.

Is there any other elegant way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i hope [this](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6392697?hl=en) article could help you

**Connect Firebase to Google Analytics**

1. Sign in to [your Google Analytics account.](https://analytics.google.com/analytics/web/#home/)
2. Select the Admin tab.
3. In the PROPERTY column, select Create new property from the dropdown
   menu.
4. Select Mobile app.
5. Select Firebase Analytics.
6. Under Connect to Firebase, select the Firebase app you want to
   connect. If you don't see the app listed in the dropdown, make sure
   you have created it in Firebase first and that you're signed in to
   the correct Google account.
7. Click Connect app.

**View your reports**

1. Sign in to [your Google Analytics account.](https://analytics.google.com/analytics/web/#home/)
2. Select the Admin tab.
3. In the PROPERTY column, select name of the app. (In the VIEW
    column, "all app data" should be selected, once you've selected the
    name of the app.)

You'll be taken to your Firebase Analytics reports.

Comment: Great, just what I'm looking for.
Thanks